# Não consigo enviar formulário de contato. Aparece a mensagem "Incorrect email! ao clicar em enviar

Tags: php, html, formulário

Estou tentando arrumar um formulário de contato, ele não tinha o código em php, apenas em html, sendo que na função action do codigo HTML ele mandava para o site https://mobirise.com/.

**Exemplo - HTML Como estava:**

```html
<form action="https://mobirise.com/" method="post" data-form-title="INSCREVA-SE" class="">

                        <input type="hidden" value="xF2wyA3Am9XJfPWKPUBHNyYWvEGJICdaXxc9CFcjWrbWYGSdCv/fixi4T+1Vwwm0ndVitrKbaxtbtlwtaxG18eSbhyRi2OJog/+SyB+sMh6+6cl1NPdxVeoqfOgxNecW" data-form-email="true">
```

Após criar o código em php eu retirei do código em HTML o link que estava na função action(https://mobirise.com/) e substitui colocando no lugar
a página ("enviar_email.php" ) que criei com o código em php.

Após fazer essas alterações com o intuito de fazer o formulário enviar a mensagem para o email do site, tenho o seguinte problema: após preencher o formulário e clicar em enviar aparece a mensagem "Incorrect email!". Preciso resolver esse problema, para então poder verificar se o código em php irá funcionar e fazer o envio corretamente das informações para o site.

**HTML - parte do código que alterei:**

```html
<form method="post" action="enviar_email.php"  data-form-title="INSCREVA-SE">
```

**HTML do Fomulário:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<section class="mbr-section" id="form1-0"
         style="background-color: rgb(11, 66, 128); padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 40px;">

    <div class="mbr-section mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--middle">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-xs-center">
                    <h3 class="mbr-section-title display-2">&nbsp;</h3>

                    <h3 class="mbr-section-title display-2">CONTATE-NOS</h3>
                    <small class="mbr-section-subtitle">Deixe seu nome, e-mail e receba mais informações.</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mbr-section mbr-section-nopadding" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" data-form-type="formoid">


                    <div data-form-alert="true">
                        <div hidden="" data-form-alert-success="true"
                             class="alert alert-form alert-success text-xs-center">Muito Obrigado! Em breve
                            retornaremos.
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <form method="post" action="enviar_email.php"  data-form-title="INSCREVA-SE"> <!-- os dados serão enviados para a página que está definida no action=' ' -->                     

                     

                        <div class="row row-sm-offset">

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form1-0-name" class="form-control-label style9">Nome</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required=""
                                           data-form-field="Name" id="form1-0-name"> <!-- observa o name em cada um dos campos -->
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form1-0-email" class="form-control-label style9">E-mail</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required=""
                                           data-form-field="Email" id="form1-0-email">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="form1-0-message" class="form-control-label style9">Mensagem</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="7" data-form-field="Message"
                                      id="form1-0-message"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">ENVIAR</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
   
</body>
</html>
```

**Codigo do Formulário - PHP**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>
<body>

<?
//isset checa se o botão enviar - submit foi clicado e só vai disparar o email se for verdadeiro
 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // email onde tu vai receber a mensagem
    $destinatario = 'contato@belartsolucoes.com.br';
    
 // pegando os dados do form...
    $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $mensagem= $_POST['message'];

  // headers que prepara a mensagem 
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: Site <contato@pmbasis.com.br>" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: contato@pmbasis.com.br" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();


/*abaixo contém os dados que serão enviados para o email
cadastrado para receber o formulário*/

       $corpo = "Formulario Enviado\n";
       $corpo .= "Nome: " . $name . "\n";
       $corpo .= "E-mail: " . $email . "\n";
       $corpo .= "Mensagem: " . $mensagem . "\n";
 

    // envia o email... --> 
 $resposta = mail($destinatario,$headers,$corpo, $mensagem);

    // volta para contato.html -->
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Mensagem que aparece ao clicar no botão enviar**
    [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo JS - Formoid**

```js
`code` jQuery(function(t){var e=function(){var e=("https:"==location.protocol?"https:":"http:")+"//formoid.net/api/push",a=function(){var e=(/MSIE (\d+)\./.exec(navigator.userAgent)||[0,0])[1]
return 8==e||9==e&&"file:"!=location.protocol?function(e,a){var n=new XDomainRequest,r=t.Deferred()
return n.open(a.type,e),n.onload=function(){r.resolve(this.responseText)},n.onerror=function(){r.reject()},n.send(a.data),r}:(t.support.cors=!0,t.ajax)}(),n=function(t,e){return t="__"+t+"__",e.length?(this[t]=e[0],this):this[t]},r=function(e,a,n){return t.each(n,function(t,n){e[n]=function(){return a[n].apply(a,arguments)}}),e},i=function(t){t=t||{},this.__email__=t.email||"",this.__title__=t.title||"",this.__data__=t.data||[]}
return i.prototype.email=function(t){return n.call(this,"email",arguments)},i.prototype.title=function(t){return n.call(this,"title",arguments)},i.prototype.data=function(t){return n.call(this,"data",arguments)},i.prototype.send=function(n,i){var o=r(t.Deferred(),this,["email","title","data","send"])
return i&&(i.call(this,o),"pending"!=o.state())?o:(a(e,{type:"POST",data:JSON.stringify({email:this.__email__,form:{title:this.__title__,data:arguments.length?n:this.__data__}})}).done(function(t){try{var e=JSON.parse(t)
e.error?o.reject(e.error):o.resolve(e.response)}catch(a){o.reject("Incorrect server response.")}}).fail(function(){var t="Failed to query the server. "
t+="onLine"in navigator&&!navigator.onLine?"No connection to the Internet.":"Check the connection and try again.",o.reject(t)}),o)},{Form:function(t){return new i(t)}}}(),a=function(e){if(e.checkValidity)return e.checkValidity()
var a=!0,n=t(e).val(),r=t(e).attr("type")
return n?a=!("email"===r&&!/^([^@]+?)@(([a-z0-9]-*)*[a-z0-9]+\.)+([a-z0-9]+)$/i.test(n)):t(e).attr("required")&&(a=!1),t(e)[(a?"remove":"add")+"Class"]("form-invalid"),a}
t('[data-form-type="formoid"]').each(function(){var n,r=t(this),i=r.is("form")?r:r.find("form"),o=r.find("[data-form-alert]"),s=r.is("[data-form-title]")?r:r.find("[data-form-title]"),l=r.find('[type="submit"]'),c=o.attr("data-success")||o.find("[data-form-alert-success]").html()
l.html('<span class="btn-text">'+l.html()+'</span><i class="btn-loader"></i>').click(function(){i.addClass("form-active")}),i.submit(function(d){if(d.preventDefault(),i.addClass("form-active"),!l.hasClass("btn-loading")){var f=!0,u=[]
n=n||e.Form({email:r.find("[data-form-email]").val(),title:s.attr("data-form-title")||s.text()}),o.html(""),r.find("[data-form-field]").each(function(){a(this)||(f=!1),u.push([t(this).attr("data-form-field")||t(this).attr("name"),t(this).val()])}),f&&(l.addClass("btn-loading").prop("disabled",!0),n.send(u).done(function(e){i.removeClass("form-active"),r.find("[data-form-field]").val(""),o.append(t('<div class="alert alert-form alert-success text-xs-center"/>').text(c||e))}).fail(function(e){o.append(t('<div class="alert alert-form alert-danger text-xs-center"/>').text(e))}).always(function(){l.removeClass("btn-loading").prop("disabled",!1)}))}})})})
```

Comment: Onde aparece essa mensagem? Depois que envia o form ou antes?

Comment: Ele não chega a enviar o formulário, quando clico em enviar ele aparece a mensagem.

Comment: Aparece onde?...

Comment: Ei Sam, eu editei a pergunta e adicionei o print da tela

Comment: Isso é algum plugin que tá fazendo isso. Tem que ver todo o código JS da página.

Comment: Acho que encontrei o código JS aonde pode conter o problema, tem um JS indexado com o nome formoid.min.js

Comment: Tens ai um ficheiro JS que deve estar a fazer mal a validação, e so veres qual ficheiro JS esta a ser chamada e tentares sem esse mesmo ficheiro.

Answer (score 0):

Vou deixar aqui apenas 1 exemplo como eu estou usando o phpmailer para envio de formulario de contactos, pode ajudar.

Html

```
<form class="form-contact contact_form" action="processa_contacto.php" method="post" id="contactForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control w-100" name="messagem" id="mensagem" cols="30" rows="9" placeholder="Escreva a sua mensagem" required></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="nome" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Nome" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="assunto" id="assunto" type="text" placeholder="Assunto" required>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
                        <font color="black">RGPD</font>             
                    </label>
                </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mt-3">
          <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="button button-contactForm">Enviar Mensagem</button>
            <br>
        </div>
      </form>
```

PHP - Envio de Pedido de Contacto

```
function send_mail_auth($to_email, $to_name, $from_email, $from_name, $subjectEmpresa, $subjectClient, $body) {
        require_once("sistema/mail/class.phpmailer.php");
        require_once("sistema/mail/class.smtp.php");

        $mail             = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $mail->Host       = "teste.development.pt";
        $mail->Port       = 465;
        $mail->Username   = "noreply@teste.development.pt";
        $mail->Password   = "*****";
        //$mail->AddReplyTo($email_remetente,$nome_remetente);
        $mail->From = $from_email;
        $mail->FromName = $from_name;
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->AltBody = "Para ver este e-mail, utilize um cliente de e-mail que suporte HTML.";
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $mail->AddAddress($to_email, $to_name);
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Send();

        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        $mail->ClearAttachments();

    }

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
                $to_empresa = "teste@development.pt";
                $to_name = '<strong>Nome:</strong> '.$_POST['nome'].'<br>';
                $email ='<strong>Email:</strong> '.$_POST['email'].'<br>';
                $assunto ='<strong>Assunto:</strong> '.$_POST['assunto'].'<br><br>';
                $texto= $_POST['messagem'];
                $from_email = "noreply@teste.development.pt";
                $from_name = "Teste"; 
                $subjectEmpresa = "TesteEmpresa - Novo pedido de contacto"; 


                include('emailtemplate/emailEmpresa.php');
                send_mail_auth($to_empresa,$to_name, $from_email, $_POST['nome'], utf8_decode($subjectEmpresa), utf8_decode($body));

                $subjectClient = "Teste"; 
                $to_email = $_POST['email'];        

                include('emailtemplate/emailCliente.php');
                send_mail_auth($to_email,$to_name, $from_email, utf8_decode($from_name), utf8_decode($subjectClient), utf8_decode($body));  

            }
```

É também necessário ter a biblioteca PHPMailer na raiz do site, eu neste caso também tenho o mail template porque estou a enviar 2 emails diferentes, um que é uma copia para quem envia o formulário e outro email que vai ser o email enviado para a empresa.